# Using IDebugControl::Disassemble to view the instructions of a subroutine

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, winapi, disassembly

So I'm attempting to use the windows API (DbgEng.h /.lib) 'Disassemble' function to view the instructions of a certain function (which i know is exported) in a module. However....It's returning an unexpected error.

```
IDebugClient* clt;
IDebugControl* ctrl;

void InitializeInterfaces(void)
{
    HRESULT status;

    if ((status = DebugCreate(__uuidof(IDebugClient), (void**)&clt)) != S_OK) {
        Utils::add_log("IDebugClient DebugCreate failed: 0x%X\n", status);
    }

    clt->AttachProcess(NULL, GetProcessId(GetCurrentProcess()), DEBUG_ATTACH_NONINVASIVE | DEBUG_ATTACH_NONINVASIVE_NO_SUSPEND);

    if ((status = clt->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugControl), (void**)&ctrl)) != S_OK) {
        Utils::add_log("IDebugControl QueryInterface failed: 0x%X\n", status);
    }
}

void print_bytes(const void *object, size_t size, const char* funcname)
{
    size_t i;
    Utils::add_log("|%s function bytes| ", funcname);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Utils::add_log_raw("%02x ", ((const unsigned char *)object)[i] & 0xff);
    }

    Utils::add_log_raw("\n");
}

void main()
{
    InitializeInterfaces();

    ULONG64 bc = (ULONG64)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("lua_shared.dll"), "luaL_loadbufferx");

    PSTR buff;
    HRESULT size = ctrl->Disassemble(bc, DEBUG_DISASM_EFFECTIVE_ADDRESS, (PSTR)&buff, 16, NULL, NULL);

    //error catching incase the disassemble fails (which it does fuck -___-)
    if (size == S_OK) {
        Utils::add_log("%s", buff);
    }
    else if (size == S_FALSE) {
        Utils::add_log("[error] buffer too small to recieve proccess instructions");
    }
    else {
        Utils::add_log("IDebugControl process disassemble failed: 0x%X\n", size);
    }

    //troubleshooting
    Utils::add_log_raw("\nTROUBLESHOOTING INFO\n");
    Utils::add_log("|bc function pointer| 0x%p\n", bc);
    print_bytes((const void*)bc, sizeof bc, "bc");
}
```

This is current code I'm using, and this is what it outputs:

> [04:09:56] IDebugControl process disassemble failed: 0x8000FFFF
>
> TROUBLESHOOTING INFO
>
> [04:09:56] |bc function pointer| 0x640FE750
>
> [04:09:56] |bc function bytes| 55 8b ec 83 e4 f8 83 ec

Anyone know what I'm missing to cause it to throw that error? 0x8000FFFF is equivalent to E_UNEXPECTED enum. The function pointer is valid, the bytes seem fine, I'm lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're passing NULL for the last argument (EndOffset) but the docs don't say this is optional.

Comment: I added a argument for the last parameter - " HRESULT size = ctrl->Disassemble(bc, DEBUG_DISASM_EFFECTIVE_ADDRESS, (PSTR)&buff, 16, NULL, (PULONG64)&endOffset);", it still seems to fail.

Comment: Try setting the flags to 0 instead of DEBUG_DISASM_EFFECTIVE_ADDRESS (it sounds like that's only meant to be used when actually debugging a process).

Comment: Set the flag to 0 - still returning the same E_UNEXPECTED error.

Comment: Maybe the whole API is only meant to be used for debugging a process; it might not be intended as a general purpose disassembler.

Comment: I had the same thoughts - but you would think that even if it wasn't INTENDED for general use it would still work fine right? Seems odd.

Comment: That seems like a big conclusion to jump to :)

Comment: You're probably getting the error because you're not debugging any process. The `AttachProcess` method call would have failed because a process can't debug itself.

Comment: In which case, you should spawn a separate sub-process to debug the main process that contains the code you want to disassemble, and then use an IPC mechanism to have the sub-process send the disassembly back to the main process.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue.  What fixed it for me was simply loading an IDebugSymbols interface as well.  E.g.:

```
IDebugClient* clt;
IDebugControl* ctrl;
IDebugSymbols* symbols;

void InitializeInterfaces(void)
{
    HRESULT status;

    if ((status = DebugCreate(__uuidof(IDebugClient), (void**)&clt)) != S_OK) {
        Utils::add_log("IDebugClient DebugCreate failed: 0x%X\n", status);
    }

    clt->AttachProcess(NULL, GetProcessId(GetCurrentProcess()), DEBUG_ATTACH_NONINVASIVE | DEBUG_ATTACH_NONINVASIVE_NO_SUSPEND);

    if ((status = clt->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugControl), (void**)&ctrl)) != S_OK) {
        Utils::add_log("IDebugControl QueryInterface failed: 0x%X\n", status);
    }

    if ((status = clt->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugSymbols), (void**)&symbols)) != S_OK) {
        Utils::add_log("IDebugSymbols QueryInterface failed: 0x%X\n", status);
    }
```

Once I did that disassembly worked fine.  (I was also doing an in-proc attach with the exact same flags you were using, for what it's worth.)

No idea why this little tidbit isn't documented on MSDN.  I only thought to try it based on some pseudo-code referenced in this article: https://www.gamedev.net/blog/909/entry-2254516-leveraging-windows-built-in-disassembler/

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`IDebugControl::WaitForEvent(DEBUG_WAIT_DEFAULT, timeout)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugcontrol-waitforevent) first.